# InstallShield VStudio project is installing app.config file instead of merged MyApp.exe.config

Tags: installshield

Using a InstallScript C# .Net Wizard to connect to a WinForms solution where I used the dependency scanner to identify project outputs.

The install package is copying the un-merged app.config file to the target directory instead of the solutions merged MyApp.exe.config file. This results in a executable that does not properly pickup configuration file settings not only because the file isn't named correctly but it also does not merge in target environment settings (ie. release, debug, etc.).

How do you have the Installer copy the merged MyApp.exe.config file to the Install Directory?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you add the file onto the InstallShield "Files and Folders"?

Comment: I think I gave InstallShield more credit than I should have. I expected it to be able to scan my .sln and .csproj files to find dependencies. I expected to be able to point it at a .sln file and have it build the .sln, pull updated exe's and dependency's, and then use my settings to deliver a fresh new install package.

Comment: roderickPrince, Remember, nothing is perfect! InstallShield is a good product. I have used Microsoft Deployment and InstallAware. And I have heard complaints on RPM, Red Hat's installer.

Comment: Another thing, if the tool is completely smart, then nobody needs me for using this tool :) LOL

Comment: InstallShield won't be accused of being "completely smart" by me... I have other more selective words for them though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I believe this should work.

Select the config file, and in the Copy to Output Directory under File.Properties, choose Copy always or Copy if newer. You can choose any file you like with this method. Basically this file will be placed to a directory where the binaries are built. This is still a better method than configuring/fixing from InstallShield, I think. I will like to hear from you, if you disagree.

Another thing, a config file is used and determined at run-time by code. That’s probably the reason why InstallShield does not know the file dependency on it. And it is out of scope for that tool.

Have fun and let me know what happens.

Tommy Kwee

Answer (score 1):

I am using [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to do my app.config transforms and here is what we're doing to get installshield to work.  For postbuild step, copy all files needed by installshield to a separate Install folder (i.e. copy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.*" "$(ProjectDir)bin\Install").  Point installshield to that folder to build it's output

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using SlowCheetah for my config transforms, but the real answer to this question is that the InstallShield project pays attention to the selected Solution Configuration. If you select the Release configuration before building the InstallShield project, the Release output will be used in the install package.